# Django model with crud operations

Tags: python, django, django-models

Working with Django and stuck on how to make my model c.r.u.d operations using Models.Manager.
The fields I'm working with are zipcode, city, latitude, longitude, coordinates and current time.
I would like to insert a new entry with zipcode, city, latitude, longitude and current time.
Also, would like to update an existing record by zipcode.  Lastly, get a record by zipcode returning city and get a record by zipcode returning city, state, and coordinates( latitude and longitude ).

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class Name(models.Model):
    zipcode     = models.CharField(max_length=5, primary=True, blank=False)
    city        = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    state       = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=False)
    latitue     = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False)
    longitue    = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False)
    curr_time   = models.datetime(default=datetime.now, blank=False)
```

Comment: You say stuff like "I would like" and "Also, would like".  What's your question?  Is this a request for someone doing it for you?  StackOverflow is not that kind of site!

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem, can you post what you have so far, so that we can see what you are doing wrong?

Comment: @Ken : It is not a homework question.

Comment: @luis : sorry, didn't mean to say it was a homework problem, just that it sounds like a homework problem.

Comment: How does this in any way sound like a homework problem?

Comment: @Andre : It isn't. Everyone of us gets stuck from time to time, even you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the django documentation some more https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/. The tutorial has a portion talking about saving and updating models. However, in answer to your question...

```
from models import Name
from datetime import datetime

# create a new model
name = Name(city='New York', state='NY')
# fields can also be set this way
name.zipcode = '10027'
# save the model to the database
name.save()
# find a model by zipcode
name = Name.objects.filter(zipcode='10027')
# modify it
name.curr_time = datetime.now()
# save it
name.save()
```

Easy, right?

Comment: No problem. I highly encourage you to go through the entire Django tutorial. It was very helpful for me when I was first learning Django.

Answer (score 0):

For your curr_time field, you may use:

```
curr_time = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
# or auto_now_add=True, if you want set this field only at the creation.
```

More here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datefield